# How to include custom javascript in Oracle ATG pages

Tags: javascript, oracle, atg

We would like to include custom javascript code in an Oracle ATG page which will communicate with an application over AJAX and according to the data retrieved, it will modify the info entered by the user (before save). What are the best practices to implement this? It is very important the solution to be simple to deploy/integrate with Oracle ATG.

Is there a concept similar to the MS Dynamics CRM packages in Oracle ATG? In MS CRM one can deploy a custom solution (includes custom js scripts, pages, plugins, entities etc.) directly from the administration.

Thanks in advance!

-E

Comment: Your ATG solution is built with JSP. These can include custom JS scripts which call `formhandlers` that can submit the page and respond with an `AJAX` response. Provided you include all of your customisations into your WAR file it can be deployed. It is nothing like MS Dynamics CRM.

Answer (score 0):

The information you are looking for is in the ATG Service Center UI Programming Guide which for ATG 10.2 can accessed [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35319_01/Service.10-2/ATGServiceCenterUIProgGuide/html/s0703addingjavascriptandcssfiles01.html)!